# How can I remove a TiO2 coating from my car windows?

Tags: nanotechnology

I've tried all the common solvents including hydrogen peroxide, chlorine, acetone. I tried a high speed sander with a rare earth polish. I have spoken to the head of the chemistry dept. at Cornell University and she said she did not have a remedy that would not ruin the glass. From the MDS here's what's in it:

1.Polymeric mixture with nano   5%-10%

2.Pexi Polymer   5%-10%

3.Anti static additive    5%-8%

4.Anti rust additive   3%-6%

5.Complex micro emulsion    2%-5%

6.Organofunctional siloxane blend    4%-8%

7.Synthetic nano driver polymeric fusion   10%-20%

8.Hydrogen hydroxide 40%-65%

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. The owner/developer of this coating won't take responsibility and help me get this stuff off my windows of my new car. Thank you.

Comment: "Hydrogen hydroxide" Buhahaha :D Nice joke...

Comment: The "head of the chemistry dept. at Cornell" is my favourite in this post. Troll?

Comment: "high speed sander", "rare earth polish" - nice.

Comment: @Mithoron . Hi. This is not a joke. The ingredients I listed, including hydrogen hydroxide, were taken word for word from the data sheet the developer of this product gave me when gave me this product to protect the glass from mineral deposits from my city water.

Comment: Of course you didn't know it's babble.  That makes it funnier :D

Comment: Well this isn't going like I'd hoped. First off I'm an illustrator so I have very little knowledge of what the ingredients in this coating are or do other than the many hours I've spent researching this on line of late. That's why I posted this question here in hopes someone who knows much more about chemistry might have a suggestion on how to get this stuff off my windows. I did speak with Melisa Hines at Cornell yesterday and I did hire a glass cleaning company to get this off the glass. They said it was a rare earth polish.

Comment: From my understanding the purpose of $\ce{TiO2}$ layer is to absorb UV (ultraviolet) part of solar spectrum in order to reduce negative (destructive) impact on the car internals (e.g. UV-light degrades plastics), also you and your passengers. So again, why do you want to get rid of it? Does it affect the visibility? If possible, please add the photo of the glass and/or car model (ideally glass type and manufacturer, if there are visible labels).

Comment: @andselisk. Actually the Tio2 in these coatings acts as a photo catalyst  neutralizing pollutants and dirt that are easy washed away by rain etc. So it's used more for it'self cleaning properties than UV protection in auto and building applications.

Comment: @Jeffrey Oh, I didn't know that, thank you! So why do you want to get rid of this coating? It sounds like it's been put there for a good reason.

Comment: One can feel dumber just by reading these "ingredients" but your coating is probably mostly polymeric, so you could try strongly oxidating mixtures like piranha solution or  CrO3 in H2SO4 Another option is to burn it out with flame or for more gentle approach decompose with less extreme heat.

Comment: @andselisk The windows look normal until they get wet then they reveal  runs and spots from rain,water, the car windshield cleaner etc, that have sat on the coating for any length of time. These runs etc once "set in" have to be smoothed out by repolishing. So the windows appear normal again until you get water on them again and the whole cycle repeats. So the coating doesn't go away it just becomes more uniform after polishing. I have a video showing this but I'm not sure how to get it fro m my computer to this site. I also have all the Toyota glass specs.

Comment: @Mithoron In the data sheet under heading Reactivity and sub heading Incompatibility it says Strong Oxidizing agents. So I researched that  and tried hydrogen peroxide and pool chlorine. The peroxide had some effect in the sense that the area I working became less slippery temporarily. What is piranha solution or CrO3 inH2SO4? I don't want to try to burn it off  that would probably melt the rubber gaskets around the windows. The data sheet claims it has a boiling point of 180-240F. Also states the PH is 7.2-7.6 if that helps.

Comment: Related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/84001/removing-polyimide-coating-without-damaging-carbon-nor-fused-silica-optical-fibe This "data" of yours is about solution (FYI "hydrogen hydroxide" is water...) which was used to make the coating. Like anything strong enough to remove coating, could also damage rubber, so window has to be taken out from the door before operation.

Answer (score 1):

The head of the chemistry department at Cornell University is right.

The only advice I have is to wait. Eventually the ravages of time shall triumph over the titan's fiendishness.

Comment: I have seen photos of sections of buildings that had been treated with this stuff and after 6 years it was still on there and working. I was hoping to find a way to get this coating off my windows a little sooner than that.