# Removing polyimide coating without damaging carbon nor fused silica optical fiber

Tags: polymers

While being manufactured, an optical fiber (fused silica, 125 microns diameter) has been coated with a carbon coating (~50 microns thick) and an external, ~60 microns thick, polyimide coating.

The problem is removing the external coating but not damaging the carbon layer or the glass core. Several procedures are recommended to remove polyimide coatings, being the more usual:

- thermal (flame),
- chemical (hot sulfuric acid -> within seconds),
- mechanical (razor).

After a little research on flame temperatures and other chemical methods (which is a completely unknown field for me), I [have found](http://www.molex.com/mx_upload/superfamily/polymicro/pdfs/polyimide_removal_from_silica_fibers_or_tubes.pdf) that sodium hydroxide would also attack polyimide while being much easier for me to get than hot sulfuric acid. The questions are: how long could it take to remove the coating along a few cm? Would it damage the carbon layer?

Is there any method I could try?